# How to post extjs data from form to server?

Tags: javascript, extjs, web-applications, sencha-touch, extjs5

I have understood how to GET data from server to application.
Now I face with POST task.
I have form, and want post fields data to server by clicking on button.

I trying to use this:

```
{//some controllercode

          xtype: 'button'  
          text: 'save',
          ui: 'confirm',
          scope: this,
          handler: function() {
              Ext.Ajax.request({
                  url:'/api/renter/',
                  method: 'POST',
                  params: {
                      ReplaceAllRefs: true
                  }
              })

              }
          }
```

what the parameter of Ext.Ajax defines data which will post to server through url?
I can use this class for POST task or isn't the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i have used this block of code:

```html
{
              text: 'save',
              ui: 'confirm',
              handler: function() {
                 
                 var dataup3 = this.up().items.items[0]; 
//get form's fields level
                 var dataSet3 = dataup.getValues();
                 
                 Ext.Ajax.request({
                  url:'/api/cutarea/',
                  method: 'POST',
                  params: dataSet3
                 })
                }
}
```

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 3):

if you want to post form data you can use `form.submit` method instead of `Ext.ajax`..

```
 var form  = your_form_panel.getForm();
 if(form.isValid()){ //isValid() will validate all your form fields 
      form.submit({
            url : '/api/renter/',
            params: params,    //additional parameters can be send in object
            success: function(form, o){

            },
            failure: function(form, o){

            }
      });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the ExtJs documentation of [Ext.Ajax.request](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.Ajax.html#method-request) for the option `jsonData`.

> jsonData :  Object/String
>
> JSON data to use as the post. Note: This will be used instead of params for the post data.
>   Any params will be appended to the URL.

So your Ajax request should look like

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:'/api/renter/',
    method: 'POST',
    jsonData: {
        ReplaceAllRefs: true
    }
});
```

When you want to submit GET and POST data you can do it with `params` and `jsonData`.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:'/api/renter/',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        someGetParam: 'value'
    },
    jsonData: {
        ReplaceAllRefs: true
    }
});
```